# GSpread Column Sizing

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am trying to adjust the width of columns in a google sheet using GSpread, however I can't find any documentation on the subject all across the web. I have tried the actual project documents itself, and stack overflow.

I have looked through the documentation, and stack overflow, and nobody has asked a question like this before.

No code to show, as I haven't found any that may be relevant.

I am expecting the widen column 'A' in my sheet by around 100.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Cheers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- You want to know how to adjust the width of the column of Google Spreadsheet using gspread.

  - You want to set the column "A" to 100 pixels.
- You have already been able to put and get values to the Spreadsheet using gspread.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? In this modification, `batch_update()` method is used.

#### Sample script:

Please set `spreadsheetId`, `sheetName` and the gridrange of `range`.

```
spreadsheetId = "###"
sheetName = "Sheet1"

client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
ss = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
sheetId = ss.worksheet(sheetName)._properties['sheetId']
body = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "updateDimensionProperties": {
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": sheetId,
                    "dimension": "COLUMNS",
                    "startIndex": 0,
                    "endIndex": 1
                },
                "properties": {
                    "pixelSize": 100
                },
                "fields": "pixelSize"
            }
        }
    ]
}
res = ss.batch_update(body)
```

#### Note:

- Please set the range as the gridrange.

  - In this sample script, `startIndex: 0` and `endIndex: 1` mean the column "A" because of `dimension: "COLUMNS"`.
- In this sample script, the width of the column "A" is set to 100 pixels.
- When `dimension` is changed to `ROWS`, the height of rows can be adjusted.

#### References:

- [batch_update(body)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api/models/spreadsheet.html#gspread.spreadsheet.Spreadsheet.batch_update)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [UpdateDimensionPropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatedimensionpropertiesrequest)

If this was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: Also worked perfectly! Really appreciate the help with this.

Comment: @Dylan Logan Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using gspread I recommend to use [gspread-formatting](https://pypi.org/project/gspread-formatting/) for this task.

Example from the documentation:

```
set_row_height(worksheet, 1, 42)
set_row_height(worksheet, '1:100', 42)
set_row_heights(worksheet, [ ('1:100', 42), ('101:', 22) ])
set_column_width(worksheet, 'A', 190)
set_column_width(worksheet, 'A:D', 100)
set_column_widths(worksheet, [ ('A', 200), ('B:', 100) ])
```

Check it here: https://pypi.org/project/gspread-formatting/#setting-row-heights-and-column-widths

Comment: Works great for my needs, thanks!